# SQL function which iteratively replaces substring

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to mysql functions, I have a string of comma separated integers,

```
x = '14,42,36,2,56,23,...'
```

I want to create a function which removes the first `i` integers.

I have a function which does for the first integer only:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS SPLIT_STR;
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(x VARCHAR(20000), delim VARCHAR(1), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1), delim, ',');
```

Comment: SQL is just not the laguage for that kind of string manipulation. Do it in your logic or change your DB structure if the string comes from the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with delimiter-separated strings usually is a bad idea in SQL. I hope your issue isn't related to *Jaywalker anti-pattern* (i.e. holding multiple values in one column).

However, in your particular case this can be resolved with:

```
-- delete @count integers from start
SET @count = 3;
SET @data  = '14,42,36,2,56,23';
SET @delit = ',';
SELECT SUBSTRING(@data, CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@data, @delim, @count))+2);
```

-or, with one query, as:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(@data, CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@data, @delim, @count))+2) 
FROM
  (SELECT @data:='14,42,36,2,56,23', @count:=3, @delim:=',') AS init;
```

Comment: it works, thanks :)
one addition, how to include condition where sum of integers of @data < n

Comment: That's where you came to SQL restrictions. No - you can't easily get that. It's better to do in application.